# Oracle SQL ORA-01403: no data found error

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Hi there I already seen other posts with the same error code, but I can't figure it out.
I have this table 'NOLEGGIO' created in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE NOLEGGIO(
  idNoleggio INT PRIMARY KEY,
  dataNoleggio DATE,
  dataRestituzione DATE,
  dataRestituito DATE,
  CF CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  prezzo NUMBER(4),
  --SEVERAL CONSTRAINTS...
```

All I want to do now is a trigger that sets a 'dataRestituzione' := :NEW.dataNoleggio + INTERVAL '3' DAY; (that means returnDate := :NEW.rentalDATE ) IF the date of membership is < than a specific date.
I show you my 'TESSERATO' table (tesserato stands for membership)

```
CREATE TABLE TESSERATO(
  numTessera INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  dataTesseramento DATE,
  dataScadenza DATE,
  CF CHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
  -- CONSTRAINT...
```

If I execute the query outside my trigger (coming next) it works (because I have datas in the fields i'm looking at) but if I insert this query in the trigger, it doesn't work!

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_NOLEGGIO
BEFORE INSERT ON NOLEGGIO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
DATAT DATE;
BEGIN
       :NEW.idNoleggio := id_noleggio.NEXTVAL;

       SELECT T.dataTesseramento INTO DATAT
       FROM NOLEGGIO N JOIN TESSERATO T ON N.CF=T.CF
       WHERE DATAT < TO_DATE('27/02/2014','DD/MM/YYYY');
  /* Here I've even tried to do something like:
       IF DATAT < TO_DATE.... THEN  . But it doesn't work either.
      However the query that actually works if I execute outside the trigger is the SELECT above.
  */

       :NEW.dataRestituzione := :NEW.dataNoleggio + INTERVAL '3' DAY;

END;
/
```

It says No data Found error, while there are datas in the rows instead!! (In fact doing the select outside the trigger matches several rows).

It's definitely driving me crazy ! Cannot understand what I do wrong.
Thank you in advance for anyone that get involved into this.

---

Insert staments for the two tables

```
 -- NOLEGGIO
 INSERT INTO NOLEGGIO VALUES(001,'18-OTT-2013','20-OTT-2013',NULL,'P3SDTI85A15H501H',10);
 INSERT INTO NOLEGGIO VALUES(002,'15-NOV-2013','19-NOV-2013',NULL,'CNTNDR89T42F839M',700);
 --idRental,dateRental,dateReturn,dateReturned,SSN,price)

-- TESSERATO
INSERT INTO TESSERATO(dataTesseramento,dataScadenza,CF) VALUES('07-set-2013','07-set-2014','RDLVRT70M08F205K');
-- SEVERAL INSERTS MORE
-- N.B. the numTessera is made with a sequence in another trigger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer Following Comments**

I have put together a test script for this. The new code used for the trigger seems to work correctly updating the return date if a valid membership exists within the date requirements set. Feel free to just take the trigger code and discard the rest, I have just included this as it is what I have used to verify that the trigger performs an update when it should:

**CAUTION: I am dropping tables in this test to make it rerunable, so i would only recommend using the full script in a test environment**

```
/****************   R U N   O N C E   ********************/
--CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE id_noleggio
--  MINVALUE 0
--  MAXVALUE 1000000000
--  START WITH 1
--  INCREMENT BY 1
--  CACHE 20;
/********************************************************/

/******************  R E R U N A B L E   ****************/

drop table NOLEGGIO;
drop table TESSERATO;

CREATE TABLE NOLEGGIO(
  idNoleggio INT PRIMARY KEY,
  dataNoleggio DATE,
  dataRestituzione DATE,
  dataRestituito DATE,
  CF CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  prezzo NUMBER(4));

CREATE TABLE TESSERATO(
  numTessera INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  dataTesseramento DATE,
  dataScadenza DATE,
  CF CHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY);

-- TESSERATO
INSERT INTO TESSERATO(numTessera, dataTesseramento, dataScadenza, CF) VALUES(1, '15-NOV-2013','15-NOV-2014','ABCDEFGHI0000001');
INSERT INTO TESSERATO(numTessera, dataTesseramento, dataScadenza, CF) VALUES(2, '01-MAR-2014','01-MAR-2015','ABCDEFGHI0000002');
-- SEVERAL INSERTS MORE
-- N.B. the numTessera is made with a sequence in another trigger

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_NOLEGGIO
BEFORE INSERT ON NOLEGGIO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   CUT_OFF_DATE DATE := TO_DATE('27/02/2014','DD/MM/YYYY');
   MEMBER_EXISTS VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
   DATAT DATE;
BEGIN

   :NEW.idNoleggio := id_noleggio.NEXTVAL;

   -- membership exists
   SELECT 'Y', T.dataTesseramento
     INTO MEMBER_EXISTS, DATAT
     FROM TESSERATO T 
    WHERE T.CF = :NEW.CF
      AND T.dataTesseramento < CUT_OFF_DATE;

   -- if value returned from query above is not null...
   if MEMBER_EXISTS = 'Y' then
      :NEW.dataRestituzione := :NEW.dataNoleggio + INTERVAL '3' DAY;
   end if;

exception
   when no_data_found then
      -- e.g. if there are no records in the TESSERATO table with the same CF value
      null; -- no action required, this will just stop an error being flagged

END;
/

-- test trigger
-- should set dataRestituzione (a valid membership exists within date requirements)
INSERT INTO NOLEGGIO VALUES(004, '01-Mar-2014', NULL, NULL, 'ABCDEFGHI0000001', 20); -- should set dataRestituzione
-- should not set dataRestituzione (membership too recent)
INSERT INTO NOLEGGIO VALUES(004, '01-Mar-2014', NULL, NULL, 'ABCDEFGHI0000002', 30);
-- should not set dataRestituzione (no record of membership in TESSERATO table)
INSERT INTO NOLEGGIO VALUES(1, '18-OCT-2013', NULL, NULL, 'P3SDTI85A15H501H', 10); 
INSERT INTO NOLEGGIO VALUES(2, '15-NOV-2013', NULL, NULL, 'CNTNDR89T42F839M', 700);
--idRental,dateRental,dateReturn,dateReturned,SSN,price)

-- look at results
select * from TESSERATO;
select * from NOLEGGIO;
```

I think that the key problem with the way that you were trying to do this before is that you were joining to the NOLEGGIO table to retrieve data that had not yet been inserted.

**Previous Answer**

Try chaining the line:

```
WHERE DATAT < TO_DATE('27/02/2014','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

to:

```
WHERE T.dataTesseramento < TO_DATE('27/02/2014','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

It looks like you are using this variable for a where condition before you have assigned a value to it i.e. it doesn't know the value if `DATAT` until the query has completed, but you are trying to use this value within the query.

Comment: @user3481005 Okay, to investigate further I would need to see some data in the tables. If you can add to the question a few insert statements for each table I will have another look.

Comment: All right! I added the insert statements for the two tables in the question. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I just changed the trigger code you putted and it works like a charm! Many Many Thanks to you. Very fast,clean and precise. Thanks again

Comment: I'm just sorry that I can't vote you up cuz I don't have enough reputation.